# Check box data context issue inside data template of column

Tags: wpf, telerik, datacontext, radgridview

I have the following structure in my UI. I am trying to have a checkbox, which will fire a command and I want to get the row as command parameter.

```
<telerik:GridViewColumn  Header="Rbl">
   <telerik:GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
         <CheckBox  
            Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type UserControl},Mode=FindAncestor}, Path=DataContext.IsRblMappedChangedCommand}"
            CommandParameter="{Binding Path=DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=telerik:GridViewRow}}"/>
      </DataTemplate>
   </telerik:GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
</telerik:GridViewColumn>
```

This triggers my command in the view model, and I get the data context as command parameter. The issue comes when I set the `IsChecked` property of the checkbox.

```
<DataTemplate>
   <CheckBox  IsChecked="{Binding IsRblMapped}"
              Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type UserControl},Mode=FindAncestor}, Path=DataContext.IsRblMappedChangedCommand}"
              CommandParameter="{Binding Path=DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=telerik:GridViewRow}}"/>
</DataTemplate>
```

After this I start getting the data context as `null`. Any idea why this happens and how to fix it?

Comment: The issue does not seem to be caused by the code you provided. Binding the `IsChecked` property should work fine with the command.

Comment: I do understand that it sounds strange, but it does happen.
I verified this, in the same code when I remove the IsChecked binding, I get the data context.
I also sent the 'GridViewRow' as command parameter, still the same, without 'IsChecked'  I get DataContext from row. When I set IsChekced row.DataContext is null.

PS @thatguy Thanks for formatting my question.

Comment: I have tested it with your code, but I was not able to reproduce the issue on my site.